# Gradle access module class

Tags: java, gradle, byte-buddy

I have two modules (A and B).

In module A I have a class called `Plugin.java` and I want to reference it in module B `build.gradle` since the plugin configuration I'm using is expecting a class.

```
byteBuddy {
    transformation {
        plugin = com.modulea.Plugin::class.java
    }
}
```

This fails but for instance If I reference a class in a JAR it works.

Any way to make this work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would specify locations to discover the module from:

```
byteBuddy {
    discoverySet = project(:myOtherProject)
    transformation {
        plugin = com.modulea.Plugin::class.java
    }
}
```